# Use column from Raster Attribute Table as Legend in Leaflet Map

Tags: raster, r, leaflet, attribute-table, legend

I have a simple `RasterLayer` in R. I added a column to the attribute table and would like to use these values in the legend of my `leaflet`-map. 
The `RasterLayer` looks like this:

```
> layer1
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 38, 40, 1520  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
extent     : 4303000, 4343000, 3365000, 3403000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : ue65 
values     : 1, 5  (min, max)
attributes :
 ID VALUE percentage
  1     1          0
  2     2       0-15
  3     3      15-20
  4     4      20-25
  5     5        >25
```

And the code for making the leaflet map like this:

```
leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles('Esri.WorldImagery',group='Imagery') %>%
  addProviderTiles('Esri.WorldStreetMap', group='Streets') %>%
  addRasterImage(layer1, colors = pal, opacity = 0.7, group = "layer1") %>%
  addLayersControl(
    baseGroups = c("Imagery", "Streets"),
    overlayGroups = c("layer1"),
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)
  ) %>%
  addLegend(pal = pal, values = values(layer1$percentage))
```

I just cant figure out how to use the `percentage`-column from the attributes table in my legend. If I use: 
`values = values(layer1)`
it shows 1-5 in the legend. Any hint would be superhelpfull!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me. Note how to get the names from the `percentage` column of the first set of `levels` of the raster, and I had to use `colors=` instead of `pal=` in `addLegend`, and made the `pal` object with `pal=rainbow(5)`:

```
leaflet() %>%
 addProviderTiles('Esri.WorldImagery',group='Imagery') %>%
 addRasterImage(layer1, colors = pal, opacity = 0.7, group = "layer1") %>% 
 addLegend(colors=pal,labels=levels(layer1)[[1]]$percentage)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick answer! Don't know how you guys can solve these things so quickly. Anyways: Thanks a lot:)

Comment: Would have been quicker if I hadn't had to make a sample raster! I've just been teaching R/geospatial so this is all fresh in my head. And answering Qs here keeps it fresh.

Comment: thanks a lot!! I hope that some day I'll also be able to answer questions and not only post a lot of questions. Do you maybe have any hint for a good ressource (I'm currently reading the Geocomputation with R and super liking it) for R/geospatial topics?

Comment: @Spacedeman Is there an official documentation page where I can check the code?